# Is it possible to connect to a database stored in Google Cloud VM instance from a Google App Engine instance without using a VPC connector?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, connection, cloud, virtual-machine

I have a project running on APP Engine that must connect to a database located on a Google Cloud VM instance. The project works normally when I run it from my local machine but after deployment it can't connect to the database. After some research I found out that we can use a VPC connector, but this is not a free service. As far as I could understand, the VPC connector allows me to use the internal ip instead of an external ip. For me, there would be no problem using an external ip, but I don't know if that's possible (I'm using a standard GAE environment). Is there any other way to make the connection works without using the VPC connector?

Comment: Are the VM instance that the db lives on and the App Engine app in the same region and VPC network?

Comment: While answering that, it SOUNDS to me like a firewall problem. To confirm you could create a new firewall rule (https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list) which applies to the DB VM, and allow connections from all sources for the ports for your DB (3306 for MySQL, 5432 for PG, etc). If that's the case, you then could narrow down the IPs you allow from to the GAE's outgoing IP. Better is to stick on private IP the whole way, but as you say, it can get complicated and more expensive.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. No it wasn't a firewall rule. The was in the pg_hba.conf postgre settings file. I followet this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres.

Comment: The problem is that when i put the app engine instance ip in the line "host    all             all           [YOUR_IPV4_ADDRESS]/32         md5" the connection doesn't work. However when i put 0.0.0.0/0 it works. Probably i'm not putting the right GAE instance ip address. Can you help to find the right one?

Comment: Yeah, the IP address listed on the AppEngine instance is the inbound address, not the outgoing. This doc talks about it: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/outbound-ip-addresses. To set up something static (single IP) gets pricy, but you can see the ranges there to allowlist so you don't to open it wide to 0.0.0.0/0.